# Chrome extension safely communicate from executed script to background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that opens an iframe in the current tab.

I need to be able to highlight some text on the webpage, and have it appear in the iframe.

However, it would be unsafe to simply use postmessage as a malicious website could take advantage of that and spam the iframe.

So, I think, and I could be wrong, that I have to have my executed script transmit the highlighted text to the background script which could then inject some script into my iframe to display the text.

How can I communicate between an executed script (chrome.tabs.executeScript) and the background script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the iframe points to a file exposed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and its src is properly formed e.g. `chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html')`, this iframe.html will be running in a document with a `chrome-extension://` URL which has the same privileges as your background script or browser_action script.

In other words, this iframe script can use the safe [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) directly.

iframe.html:

```
<script src=iframe.js></script>
```

iframe.js:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'getFrameData', {frameId: 0}, processData);
});

function processData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

content.js:

```
function createFrame(data) {
  const el = document.createElement('iframe');
  el.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html');
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function _(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg === 'getFrameData') {
      sendResponse(data);
      setTimeout(() => chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(_));
    }
  });
}
```

And of course port-based messaging can be used as well.

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this without a content script and instead by using execute script? From what I understand, a script that is executed in a page does not have access to the Chrome API's. 

Thanks!

Comment: The code specified in executeScript is a content script by definition. It executes in the same isolated world of content scripts, not as a page script, so it has access to chrome.runtime API as any other content script.